# How to Join data from 2 different tables in a single JTable

Tags: java, swing, join, jtable, tablemodel

Im making a program for employee management system.. Now I am making the CRUD form for Employee registration, i seperated the src code in data layer , business logic and gui.. In gui I separated gui view and gui model, in Gui model i created a EmployeeTableModel , to specify how I want to show data for employee Table , but in that table i got datas that come from more than one table , one is Employee table from database another one is Phone .. I have successfully get the data from Employee Table , and i can put those data in both Employee Table and Phone table in database , but I can't get them into the TableModel, I can only get the datas from employee.

[PHOTO OF THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKfTb.png)

[ALL SOURCE CODE HERE - GIT](https://bitbucket.org/vj40639/emp_repository_/src)

I tried changing the code in my EmployeeTableModel to accept more columns and to make a way to add datas from telephone table too , but didn't worked because each employee has 2 -3 phone numbers and the Employee_ID is specified as a foreign key on Phone table ..Each employee has 3 phones as I said and when we specify which phone we want to get , it's depenedent from employee_id that is foreign key  in Phone table.

```
public class PunetoriTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

List<Punetori> list;
TelefoniRepository tr = new TelefoniRepository();
PunetoriRepository pr = new PunetoriRepository();

String[] cols = {"Nr.", "Nr-Departmentit", "Emri", "Mbiemri", "Email", "Qyteti","Adresa","tel1","tel2"};

public PunetoriTableModel() {
}

public PunetoriTableModel(List<Punetori> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public void addList(List<Punetori> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return cols[col];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void remove(int row) {
    list.remove(row);
}

public Punetori getPersoni(int index) {
    return list.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return cols.length;
}

public String getDateToString(Date d) {
    DateFormat da = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return da.format(d);

}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
     Punetori p = list.get(rowIndex) ;


        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return p.getPunetoriID();
            case 1:
                return p.getDepartmentiId();
            case 2:
                return p.getEmri();
            case 3:
                return p.getMbiemri();
            case 4:
                return p.getEmail();
            case 5:
                return p.getQyteti();
            case 6:
                return p.getAdresa();




            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If employee has 3 phones, you need 3 columns (to display each of them) and object mapping between employee and his phones (so your Employee class has method like `List<String> getPhones();`).

Comment: Please put the data classes and the code how you are retrieving them from your database. (Are you using JPA?)  We can't really understand what your problem actually is.

Comment: I am using JPA and I have created an interface and repository classes for each table that is generated by database {Entity Classes} , in interface i have the methods for CRUD operations , in repository I implement them using jpa Entity manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all decide what your columns are going to be. You seem to be confused what these columns should be, when some employees have more than one phone. It is not clear what your problem is, but probably just drawing it on a piece of paper will already clear your mind.

Decide also whether these columns are going to be fixed, or dynamic (i.e. is it possible to get more columns for some employees, that you will need to add to your table?)

Second, create a separate data structure, lets call this class `EmployeeData`, that captures the information you want. Make this separate from the `PunetoriTableModel`. Populate this from your data repositories. 
Inside this put the necessary logic that decides which phone to use, or whatever custom business logic you need.

Make the `EmployeeData` provide a few public methods like `getColumns()`, `getRowCount()` and `getRow(int i)` etc.

In the constructor of your `PunetoriTableModel` just pass the `EmployeeData` and inside the respective methods call the `EmployeeData` ones. This way the table model sees the data as a table, and you have your custom logic which combines it from different tables into one which is separate.

Comment: Sergiy Medvynskyy and jbx ,  thanks for the answers.. Just to be more specific , I have the EmployeeTableModel(PersoniTableModel) that has all the data that come from Employee table in database, but the thing  is i can't call those attributes in the [ case block] because first it should be specified for which employee ID am i calling the method..

 example:case 7:{
return t.getTel1();
case 8:
return t.tel2();

}

Comment: @ValonJanuzaj You haven't provided your data classes so we can't really understand what your problem is. However, that is why I am proposing to abstract your logic in a specific class that does this. I presume that if you know that your employee of row 1 has id 123 then you can get the telephone number of row 1 by getting the telephone number of employee Id 123.

Comment: here we go bro because i couldn't add all the code 
https://bitbucket.org/vj40639/emp_repository_/src @jbx

Comment: @ValonJanuzaj Your `Punetori` class has a `telefoniCollection`. So you can do `p.getTelefoniCollection()` to get the list of `Telefoni` for your employee in the row, and slot them in the right column. Can't see what your problem is.

Comment: yes bro it has the getTelefoniCollection and if i call that even tho that i have datas in Phone table, and there is a foreign key of Employe_id , I still get a null poiner exception , but even if I get those data , how I am supposed to put them in TableModel..
I am a beginner in java so don't get pissed of me bro:P
btw thank you very much

Comment: @ValonJanuzaj NullPointerException is unrelated to the table. If the data is properly populated, can't you just do `p.getTelefoniCollection()` after `Punetori p = list.get(rowIndex) ;`? You will get all the telephone numbers, and you can decide which one to put in which column you want.